# Symfony2 SonataAdmin overriden AbstractAdmin does not understand fields

Tags: php, symfony, admin, sonata

So I override `AbstractAdmin` because I wanted to add some functions and that all of my admin classes would have it.

It looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;

class BaseAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{

....

}
```

As you can see my `BaseAdmin` extends the default sonata `AbstractAdmin` class. Everything works fine and all my classes have the custom functions if I extend the new BaseAdmin like: `class ProductAdmin extends BaseAdmin`

But I noticed one strange thing...

I have a class that uses 'file' type to upload images.

If I extend my admin class with `BaseAdmin` the form field 'file' is made into a textarea (all other simple textfields are transformed to textarea too for some reason). If I extend the default `AbstractAdmin` everything works fine..

Do I need to specify my new admin class somewhere in the configs maybe or what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You should show us some more code but from what you already told i would say this is because you override methods in the `ProductAdmin` class.

In your `BaseAdmin` class you override `AbstractAdmin` methods and you call `parent::method()` but when overriding a method in a class extending `BaseAdmin` you have to call `AbstractAdmin::method()` instead of `parent::method()` as you need to call the grand parent method and not the parent one.

Hope that helps